# How to apply an arbitrary number of rules to objects (that may have interactions between rules that cannot be determined ahead of time)?

Tags: java, algorithm, rule-engine

Suppose that I have a game that has fairly simple rules, but may have any number of rules modifiers. (For boardgames, the classical example would be Cosmic Encounter). The base rules are easy to program, but you cannot write all the conditional logic at the time. For example, if your game has 100 possible modifiers (but say only 5 are active at a time) that's 100 choose 5 possibilities and you can't enumerate them manually. So how is this done?

(This could also be for any business logic rules engine, but games are where I seem to encounter this more often).

I would think you might be able to do this by having "state" objects and then passing them through a series of modifier objects, but I'm not sure this is the right way of doing it. What is the technique / style for this? What are some good primers/examples?

(I can program well enough, but with my EE degree have only whatever theory I've picked up on the job....).

Comment: You might get a better answer on Game Development: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thank you, I will post there.